# ListView inside ConstraintLayout - items centered

Tags: android, listview, android-constraintlayout

I've defined a ListView inside a ConstraintLayout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblTitlePlan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="title"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layoutTopContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblTitlePlan"
    >
 ...
</RelativeLayout>

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listContainers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="80dp"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutTopContainer"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is that when there is only a couple of items displayed in the ListView, they are vertically centered. I'd like them to be in the top of the listView.
I think the problem comes from the constraints (layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf and layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf) that seem to also apply to the items; because if I remove them the items are in the top (but then my listview is in a bad position).

How could I solve that?

Answer (score 4):

Set `layout_height="0dp"`, this will set it to match the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listContainers"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layoutTopContainer" 
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Do something like below, It work for me
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />
```